# Start-Process Not Enough Quota

Tags: powershell, azure

I am trying to do some performance testing, launching Azure-VMs, downloading lots of versions of our software onto them and pointing at our server. I have a problem when trying to start the software, I get this error consistently when I try and start the 16th instance of our software (Very lightweight, not a great deal of memory footprint).

```
This command cannot be run due to the error: Not enough quota is available to process this command.
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (:) [Start-Process], InvalidOperationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : InvalidOperationException,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.StartProcessCommand
```

I am remote powershelling in with Invoke-Command and attempting to start the processes with Start-Process. (Where $Session has been setup beforehand)

```
Invoke-Command -Session $Session -ScriptBlock {

$currentNo = 0

1..20 | ForEach-Object{

    Start-Process -FilePath "C:\Client\$currentNo\Client.exe"
    $currentNo = $currentNo + 1
}
}
```

This is definitely not to do with memory or disk space as I have tried this on an 8 core machine with 16 GB worth of memory. This works if I remote desktop in and run the exact same script through a remote desktop window.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're probably hitting the default process limit for Powershell Remote sessions. See this article: [Configuring WSMAN Limits](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/powershell/archive/2010/05/03/configuring-wsman-limits.aspx)

Perhaps specifically this:

MaxProcessesPerShell 15